# ATLAS dimensions, DOF locations

Tags: kinematics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

Can anyone have the draw of ATLAS links dimensions and DOF distribution and location?

Best!,

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2284/atlas-dimensions,-dof-locations/) by [mariof4](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/303/mariof4/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Atlas is specified via URDF, [its documentation with graphical illustrations can be found here](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/model).

The [Atlas URDF starts out as a xacro macro](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/084739a7530d/ros/atlas_description/robots/atlas.urdf.xacro?at=default), as indicated in the header, `atlas.urdf.xacro` uses macros defined in included [`atlas_simple_shapes.urdf`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/084739a7530dd022180fee281b1d5ccffc6bbeb6/ros/atlas_description/urdf/atlas_simple_shapes.urdf?at=default) and others to expand into `atlas.urdf` at compile time.

Basic idea reiterated here:

A `Model` is composed of a collection of rigid-body **`Link`**s and **`Joint`** constraints.  The transform between **`Link`**s are defined in corresponding **`Joint`** blocks.  So for example, take a look at [this **`Joint`** block in `atlas_simple_shapes.urdf.xacro`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/084739a7530dd022180fee281b1d5ccffc6bbeb6/ros/atlas_description/urdf/atlas_simple_shapes.urdf?at=default#cl-800):

```
<joint name="back_lbz" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.0125 0 0" rpy="0 -0 0" />
    <parent link="pelvis" />
    <child link="ltorso" />
    ...
</joint>
```

Above basically says: The transform from **`pelvis Link frame`** to **`ltorso Link frame`** is defined by a linear translation of `(-0.0125, 0, 0)`, followed by Euler rotation of `(0, 0, 0)` radians.

A set of c++ URDF data structures are described [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/urdfdom_headers/src/ca602089df74d525d61830f2d0c57b0f24ced357/urdf_model/include/urdf_model?at=default) and a corresponding parser is in [urdfdom](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/urdfdom/src/121ebcdb2888d73d137ed46929be9b5328f3fa56/urdf_parser/include/urdf_parser/urdf_parser.h?at=default).

## Visualization

One way to visualize URDF model is with [rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz).  Starting with this [DRC Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/visualizing_logging_data), you can add a `TF` object:

[image: image description]

which will display **`Link`** frames:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-30**:
How to visualize COM of Atlas?

is it possible?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-02**:
Gazebo allows you to view the center of mass through the "View menu"